# Doubt regarding gas cost

Tags: solidity, contract-design, gas, storage, truffle-contract

Consider im having to deal with 3 uint8 values each of which are to be stored for each user.
Is the gas cost the same if i use 3 different arrays or if i use a structure array which contains the 3 uint8 values together.

```
struct Users{
  uint8 no1;
  uint8 no2;
  uint8 no3;
}
Users[] public users;
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is the gas cost the same if i use 3 different arrays or if i use a structure array which contains the 3 uint8 values together.

In your example, the three `uint8` would be packed into a single 32-byte word.

```
    struct Users{
      uint8 no1;
      uint8 no2;
      uint8 no3;
    }
```

Notice the array:

```
Users[] public users;
```

So, you have `users[0], users[1], users[2} ...`. Each would return a single `struct` that happens to contain 3x 8-bit `uint8`.

> if i use 3 different arrays

```
uint8[] no1;
uint8[] no2;
uint8[] no3;
```

To fetch or store 3, it would look something like:

```
uint8 a = no1[0]; uint8 b = n02[0]; uint8 c = no3[0];
```

Each `uint8` is individually addressable and we had to do three ops to get all three. Each one is using an entire 32-byte word because that is the smallest unit of addressable space.

We also had to do it in three steps instead of one step. So, there will be more operations to step through it. By far, the most expensive ops will be the writes. The first way, using struct, prepares a single SSTORE to one "slot" (5-20K gas). The separate arrays technique prepares three SSTORE ops to three slots (15-60K gas).

Hope it helps.